# Use Dynamic or Reflection.emit

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, dynamic

I'm new to C# and would like to ask for some direction on solving the following problem.

I've got a xml file used as a template (without knowing its content in advance). something like:

```
<Object>
  <Property name="ID">
    <Value weight="40">10000</Value>
    <Value weight="60">20000</Value>
  </Property>
  <Property name="Name">
    <Value weight="">foo</Value>
    <Value weight="">bar</Value>
  </Property>
  <Property name="Department">
    <SubProperty name="Department_ID">
      <Value weight="20">D01</Value>
      <Value weight="80">D02</Value>
    </SubProperty>
    <SubProperty name="Location">
      <Value weight="30">F01</Value>
      <Value weight="70">F02</Value>
    </SubProperty>
  </Property>
</Object>
```

I would like to read it in, do some shuffle, and export to a new xml file. Say, get the value of each property randomly, in accordance to their weights(percentage), to create a new list of mix-propertied objects, then serialize it to a new xml file.

Will this be done using Reflection.Emit to create a new "class" at runtime? Or is there any new features, like DynamicObject of C# 4.0 that I can use?

Any comment/sample is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) would meet your needs well. With all of the LINQ operators you can use to query and transform the document, it should be easy and even enjoyable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I did try LINQ, though it worked well, but the code will increase alone with the growing of the properties in the template.
So I just wondered if there's is some dynamic/robust way to solve this, even if I changed the whole property names of the template.
thanks

Comment: My thinking would be to use a query-first approach on the data to see what you have, and then perhaps build a lookup table of property names which you can use to access specific nodes...